# Variable is returned not updated from the method

Tags: java, methods

So, I write a short code that would move a "box" (rectangle) to the right. This part works well. Then, I wanted to see, how many "steps" this box makes till it stops. So, println should print the size of the console and number of steps. But it prints 'zero'.

```
 import acm.program.*;
 import acm.graphics.*;

public class animation extends GraphicsProgram{

public void run(){
    int x=0;
    GRect box = new GRect(50,50);
    add(box, 10,10);
    moveBox(box, x);
    println(getWidth() + ", " + x);
}

public int moveBox(GObject box, int x){
    while(true){
        box.move(10,0);
        pause(50);
        x++;
        if (box.getX()==getWidth()) break;
    }
    return x;
}

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should read smth about [primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning `x` inside the method, but discarding it from the caller. Reassign it to your caller's `x` variable

```
x = moveBox(box, x);
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it shows 19 steps now =) So, "return" does not do all the job. I also have to fix the returned variable, right? Thanks again

Comment: @user3349993 The `x` in `run` and the `x` in `moveBox` are completely unrelated (in the sense that changing one doesn't affect the other).

Comment: i know. I though I renamed the variables in run() to "steps", but I apparently, I forgot to do so. I was asking aobut assignment like "steps = moveBox(box, x)". But anyway. Thanks

Comment: @user Oh, the return value basically acts as the value of resolving the method invocation exception. If you don't assign it to anything, you simply discard it and it is popped off the stack.

Answer (score 1):

```
return x;
```

will just say - i am returning a value from this method.

but the caller should receive the returned value.

so to receive the returned value we should assign the returned value to some variable.

```
x = moveBox(box, x);
```

now the x on left side of = will have returned value.

if we just write `moveBox(box, x);` like this then
value is returned but no one is received it.

Comment: yeah, I got it. That's what I was asking from Sotirios Delimanolis.
Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `moveBox(box, x);` that returns a value but you don't have anything that will catch the value being thrown from the method `moveBox` either you can do something like

```
int moves = moveBox(box, x);
System.out.println("Movements : "+moves);
```

or

```
System.out.println("Movements : "+moveBox(box, x));
```

Comment: yeap, I got it from previous answers. Thanks anyway!